# How to get Control Value Form Control ID asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dynamic, entity-framework-4

I have my page fills controls dynamically So All I can get is Control ID 
So how can I get control Value or name from control ID
I tried this but nothing I get

```
  TextBox control = new TextBox { ID = _NumberFieldID + item.BlueprintFieldId, CausesValidation = true, EnableViewState = true, CssClass = "form-control ui-spinner-input spin metadatacontrol", Width = new Unit(ctrWidth + "%") };

 ctrlDivSet.Controls.Add(control);
```

and that is my experiment

```
  Control ControlValues= FindControl(_NumberFieldID + validationObject.MatchBlueprintFieldId);
```

I tried to compare two controls values 
So I used this

```
CompareValidator controlValidator = new CompareValidator()
                            {
                                ControlToValidate = control.ID,
                                ControlToCompare = _NumberFieldID + validationObject.MatchBlueprintFieldId,
                                Operator = voperator,
                                ValidationGroup = _ValidationGroup,
                            };
```

`CotrolTOCompare` can take the ID and compare its value 
I need somthing like that 
to obtain control name or value by its ID
please help

Comment: @Baronz please see it again

Answer (score 0):

Im a bit confused as to what you want so let's start from here and then I'll update to address if it's not correct :)

To get a value you can use in for ex. JavaScript you can do

```
var clientId = myTextBox.ClientId;
```

If you want to use the name to get the control

```
var textBox = (TextBox)FindControl("myTextBox");
```

Comment: Who is "myTextBox " I hasn't it's name I just have what written in the question  < the control Id is "_NumberFieldID + validationObject.MatchBlueprintFieldId"

Comment: "So how can I get control Value or name from control ID I tried this but nothing I get"    var yourClientId = ((TextBox)FindControl(_NumberFieldID + validationObject.MatchBlueprintFieldId).ClientId;   but I cant tell from your question exactly what you are looking for. If thats not it, please clarify.